# Oracle Tree Hierarchy Displayed as an Oracle Report

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, tree, oracle-apex

I am researching how to best represent an Oracle Tree Hierarchy as an Oracle Report within Oracle APEX - something like a tree grid. As the data I am trying to display maybe up to 10 levels deep, instead of using a tree, I was thinking whether it could be performed as a report.

I still need to use the START WITH and CONNECT BY PRIOR or perhaps some other means can be used.

I have noticed that when trying to create a simple tree hierarchy report using LPAD to indent nodes with spaces, Oracle APEX strips all the spaces.

Comment: Do you mean a classic report? Or some other reporting tool?

Comment: Hi Tom - want to keep it as part of Oracle APEX, so either a Classic or Interactive report (either one). Thanks.

Comment: Don't mean to just plug, but I remember from previous questions you had some issues with tree performance. A while ago I've been busy with getting an ajax tree working in apex and [made a blogpost about it (+demo/example)](http://tpetrus.blogspot.be/2013/09/implementing-ajax-tree-in-apex.html). You might take a look at it and see if it might help you.

Comment: Hi Tom - working through your example from your blog now, but using jsTree 0.9 version. I can't seem to figure out why the small triangular (expand/collapse) images are not appearing for me. I am at root level alone but cannot click on anything to expand the tree - any ideas where I am missing this CSS/images? Thanks.

Comment: The tree should use the default theming (if following my sample code), and it is jstree itself which appends a css file depending on the configured theme. Are you using the same javascript include as I described? jstree will look for the css/images in that root directory, and if using the same as apex would then it will get those files from the (apex) images directory.

Comment: Tom, does it matter that I am on version 4.2.2 of APEX?

Comment: No - it shouldn't. The tree has been the same since 4.0. If possible, can you try to implement it on apex.oracle.com? If you can't get it working there either, I'll be happy to take a look.

Comment: I will try and implement it on apex.oracle.com if I can't get it working but another question, I am using IE 8 browser - will your solution work in this browser? Thanks

Comment: I don't have it close at hand, but yes, it should. Nothing weird is happening that would make me say ie8 can't handle it.

Comment: No worries Tom. Really hope I can get your solution to work as it would be ideal for my requirement.

Comment: Unfortunately Tom, my data is humongous to process and am receiving the error with the listagg: ORA-01489 Result of string concat is too large. I read your post regarding this but unsure how to break up into CLOB pieces, inorder to get past this problem. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of lpad-ing with `' '` try using `'&nbsp;'` to preserve a space in the html output.